# SQL - merge two tables content in one table/view

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, view

I need to create a view (or a table) that holds n row values, taken from two different tables that have the same structure. For example:

table Europe

```
id    name        Country
----------------------------
1     Franz       Germany
2     Alberto     Italy
3     Miguel      Spain
```

table USA

```
id    name        Country
----------------------------
1     John        USA
2     Matthew     USA
```

The merged view has to be like this:

table WORLD

```
id    name        Country
----------------------------
1     John        USA
2     Matthew     USA
1     Franz       Germany
2     Alberto     Italy
3     Miguel      Spain
```

it's possible? if it is, how?

Thanks in advance for your help, best regards

Comment: why you want to create table/view? you just got the result by simple sql query

Comment: @BhavinChauhan If it's a commonly requested view on a large dataset, it could plausibly be more efficient if he just has a view or table with the result of the large query already.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

if you just want to result than try union query

```
SELECT id,name,Country FROM dbo.Europe
UNION
SELECT id,name,Country FROM dbo.USA
```

Comment: I'd advise `UNION ALL` for performance purposes (assuming countries can't be in more than one table). And for sake of completeness here is a Fiddle to demonstrate your solution. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/fe7a0/1

Comment: @GarethD why does the result show European people as from USA country?

Comment: Because I haphazardly created the USA table using your expected output from the world table. This should be what you require: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/2bc32/1

Answer (score 3):

You can create a reusable view of the union like so:

```
create view allcountries as select * from usa union select * from world;
```

(name it anything you like in place of `allcountries`)

then just:

```
select * from allcountries;
```